# Naming practice for objects of a class in Python

Tags: python, oop, naming-conventions

I have this weird problem as to how to name objects of a class.

For example, consider the class:

```
>>> class DoSomething:
         pass
```

What should I call the object of this class? `do_something` or what? Since I came out of the learning stage, I used to use `x`, `y` or `z` or whatever came to my mind. But now since I am learning to write proper code and not the language, I always face this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think "DoSomething" sounds more like a method name (albeit a bad one) than a class name.

Comment: Classes usually represents "Nouns" (i.e. what they *are*) while descriptive "verbs" are usually used to name functions or methods (i.e. what they *do*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name it something representative of what it's actually being used for. For instance:

```
class Cereal:
    def eat(self):
        print 'yum'

breakfast = Cereal()
breakfast.eat()
```

or

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, userid):
        # ...

admin_user = User(ADMIN_ID)
```

Comment: Aah I see. This approach is also useful.

Answer (score 2):

You should name it after what it represents. For example if I have a class `User` in a web application and I want to refer to the currently logged-in user, I name the variable `current_user`.

And if you have more objects of one class, your approach fails immediately. Giving the variable an index like `do_something1`, `do_something2` **is not and will never be an option**.

Use something **meaningful**, so that a reader of your code knows what this variable represents.

---

Btw. this applies to all programming languages, not just Python.

Answer (score 0):

One good naming practise is to give plural names to collections such as sets and lists.